# How to make a play/pause button for this slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My code cycles through a bunch of divs with a set interval, how do I make it so that when I click on the container it will pause and when I click on it again it will resume. thanks.

```js
function Divs() {
  var divs= $('#parent div'),
  now = divs.filter(':visible'),
  next = now.next().length ? now.next() : divs.first(),
  speed = 1000
  now.fadeOut(speed);
  next.fadeIn(speed);
 }
 var timesClicked = 0;
  i = setInterval(Divs, 4000);
  $("#slideshow-container").click(function() {
    timesClicked += 1;
    if (timesClicked%2==0) {
      i = setInterval(Divs, 4000);
  }
  else {
    clearInterval(i)
  }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "slideshow-container" id ="parent">
        
    <div class ='box' id = 'food'>
    <h2>Destination 1: Cafe Terrace Nanohana</h2><img class ='slideshow-image' src = 'Images/Cafe_Terrace_Nanohana.jpg'></img><p>There are a lot of rest areas along the way, but Cafe Terrace Nanohana is a favorite destination among cyclists for its convenience and its light, but satisfying, food; it’s also an official “cyclist oasis” along the Shimanami Kaido. Salad and seafood options are available for those looking for healthy snacks, as well as carbb-heavy options for cyclists who need the energy. This restaurant is located on the southwestern coast of Innoshima Island, right along the road to Ikuchi Island to the south. Serving food at less than 1,000 yen per meal, this place is sure to be packed at almost any time of day. Moreover,
        its scenic location beside the Shimanami-Kaido bridge and the sparkling sea.</p></div>
        <div class ='box' id = 'infrastructure'>
        <h2>Destination 2: Kosan-ji</h2><img class ='slideshow-image' src = 'Images/Kosanji-Monument.jpg'></img><p>Kosan-ji is a temple on the island of Ikuchijima. It belongs to the Hongan-ji school of Jodo Shinshu. It was founded by the industrialist Koso Kosanji in 1936 in honour of his deceased mother. The vast complex built around a hilltop is dotted with structures modelled on Japan’s most famous historic temples and shrines. Visitors may object that unlike Japan’s cherished religious buildings, Kosan-ji is unbearably gaudy. However, the ancient temples that we see today were once gaily painted in the same manner.The Kosan-ji Museum houses over two thousand items, including nineteen Important Cultural Properties. </p></div>
        <div class ='box' id = 'culture'>
        <h2>Destination 3:Imabari City</h2><img class ='slideshow-image' src = 'Images/Imabari.jpg'></img><p>Whether you are an avid rider or a once-in-a-while cyclist, taking in thesparkling azure waters of the Seto Inland Sea in and around Imabari is a must. The city is home to a variety of factories and historic sites which allow you to explore the culture of the area first hand.
        Imabari is home to the Shimanami Kaido , a series of nine bridges stretching across the islands of the Seto Inland Sea to Hiroshima prefecture. The 60-kilometer cycling route takes you through idyllic landscapes with pine and mikan orange lined mountains and the swirling, hypnotic whirlpools of the Kurushima Strait. You can choose to cycle the
        entire route or just complete one of the many routes around the islands. Sitting on Omishima Island is Oyamazumi-jinja Shrine, one of the oldest in Western Japan. Visit Omishima's three museums including the National Treasure Museum, which houses Japan's largest collection of samurai armor and swords.
        Omishima Art museum holds a large collection of Nihonga style paintings.If you prefer contemporary art, head to the striking Tokoro and Toyo Ito museums.</p></div>
        <div class ='box' id = 'Nature'>
        <h2>Destination 4: Setoda Sunset Beach</h2><img class ='slideshow-image' src = 'Images/Setoda.jpg'></img><p>Setoda Sunset Beach is located about 30 km after you depart from Hiroshima Prefecture.
        This beach has been selected as one of the 88 great beaches in Japan and has bright white sand with crystal-clear water. Furthermore, it owns a beautiful view of the sunset that is known to be the best in the Seto Inland Sea. Under the sunset the sky is painted a brilliant red, and the many islands on the horizons become enveloped in shadows. Light and shadow combine to create a fantastic landscape.
        After you enjoy the scenery, I recommend that you stop at the beach restaurant and have some food for a brief break. Since there are showers and locker rooms, why don’t you refresh your body and relax? </p></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please add the code using the snippet functionality. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

The reason why its not working is because you are trying to get an id in the document which does not exists.

Change `$("#slideshow-container")` to `$(".slideshow-container")`. That should make the code do what you expect from it.

Because `slideshow-container` has an `id` of `parent`, you can also choose to change `$("#slideshow-container")` to `$("#parent")`.

Also, remove closing tag from `img` that is not required in html.

I've improved your JS code a little bit, I hope it helps:

```
function slides() {
  const divs = $('#parent div'),
    now = divs.filter(':visible'),
    next = now.next().length ? now.next() : divs.first(),
    speed = 1000;
    
  now.fadeOut(speed);
  next.fadeIn(speed);
}
const intervalSpeed = 4000;
let interval = setInterval(slides, intervalSpeed);

$("#parent").click(function() {
  if (!interval) {
    interval = setInterval(slides, intervalSpeed);
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
  }
});
```